# Red, Amber, Green (RAG Status) text color dependent on field number value in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, style

Been trying to figure this out the whole day.  I am new to VF and would like some assistance in figuring this out.

I have a number value on a visualforce page that I would like to style with RAG colors dependant on the value. 
Less than 50=red
Between 50 and 74=amber
More than 74=green

So far I have been able to figure out that this can be done through the font styling.  However, I have only been able to do the red and green.  Not quite sure how to add in that third condition that will make the text turn amber through the visualforce styling.  Below is what I have for the style attribute:

```
color:{!IF(cObject__c.FieldName__c < 50, 'red', 'green')}
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

- Miguel

Comment: Look at the documentation for the `CASE` function.

Comment: Nevermind, that won't work.  Just use `IF(cond1, val1, IF(cond2, val2, val3))`

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman You can indeed use case. Just requires a bit of outside-the-box thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
{!IF(cObject__c.FieldName__c < 50, 'red', IF(cObject__c.FieldName__c < 75, 'goldenrod', 'green'))}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this worked perfectly.  Didn't know "goldenrod' was a thing.  ...The more you know.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific circumstance, you could actually use case:

```
{!CASE(MAX(0, FLOOR(cObject__c.Field_Name__c/25)), 0, "red", 1, "red", 2, "goldenrod", "green")}
```

This works because we divide by 25, so 0 and 1 cover 0-49, 2 covers 50-74, and the default value is green, which is 75 or more; this code is also capped at 0 using MAX.

Comment: a nice solution for deciles as well